# Large section of iPad OpenGL ES application not retina

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, opengl-es-2.0

I have an `OpengGL ES` app using a custom shader to display circles. See image below. (Opening it in a new window might be helpful)

If you look carefully you can see that the display seems to be **non retina** from about 50% of the width and about 75% of the height. This seems to be the case `only on iPad 3` (clients device). `Simulator` and an other `iPad Air 2` behave normally.

I used a the basic `OpenGL ES` game project bundled with XCode.

[image: problematic[1]]

Update: 
The pixelated areas are the ones highlighted in red:

[image]

Please also see closeup:

[image]

I must admit I do not know where to start debugging this, 
since it only seems to bug on the given device.

Here is the code I used to setup the context.

```
func setup()
{
    initTextures()

    self.context = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)

    if !(self.context != nil) {
        print("Failed to create ES context")
    }

    let view = self.view as! GLKView


    // Fix for "good" aspect ratio
    var frameSize = view.frame.size
    frameSize.height = frameSize.width / 1.43023255813953
    view.frame.size = frameSize

    // Should force the aspect ratio
    print("-------------")
    print("width \(view.frame.width) and height \(view.frame.height)")
    print("aspect ratio w/h \(view.frame.width / view.frame.height)")
    print("-------------")

    view.context = self.context!
    view.drawableColorFormat = .RGBA8888
    view.drawableMultisample = .multisample4X

    // Application specific code

    self.setupGL()
}
```

Update

I am drawing the circles with a custom `fragment shader`:

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec4 iResolution; // z - texWidth, w - texHeight

uniform sampler2D textureUnit;
uniform sampler2D smallPointsTextureUnit;

uniform vec2 gridSize;

#define SMOOTH(r,R) (1.0-smoothstep(R-0.09,R+0.09, r))

#define black vec3(0.0)
#define white vec3(1.0)

float circle(vec2 st, in float _radius, float pct ){
    float l = length(st - vec2(0.5));
    return 1.-smoothstep(_radius-(_radius*0.005) * pct,
                         _radius+(_radius*0.005),
                         l);
}

float stroke(vec2 uv, vec2 center, float radius, float width)
{
    float dist = length(uv-center);
    float t = 1.0 + smoothstep(radius, radius+width, dist)
    - smoothstep(radius-width, radius, dist);
    return t;
}

void main()
{
    vec2 resolution = vec2(iResolution.x, iResolution.y);

    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy;

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution;

    float colWidth  = iResolution.x / gridSize.x;
    float rowHeight = (iResolution.y + 1.0) / gridSize.y;

    float smallerSize = min(rowHeight, colWidth);
    float largerSize = max(rowHeight, colWidth);

    vec2 divider = resolution / smallerSize;

    st.x *= divider.x;
    st.y *= divider.y;

    float pct = largerSize / smallerSize;

    float texXPos = (floor(st.x * smallerSize / largerSize) + 0.5) / iResolution.z;
    float texYPos = (floor(gridSize.y -st.y) + 0.5) / iResolution.w;

    vec4 tex = texture2D(textureUnit, vec2(
                texXPos,
                texYPos));

    vec4 texSmallPoints = texture2D(smallPointsTextureUnit, vec2((floor(st.x * 2.0 * smallerSize / largerSize) + 0.5) / 128.0,
                                                                 (floor(gridSize.y * 2.0 -st.y * 2.0) + 0.5) / 128.0));
    //texSmallPoints.r = 0.5;
    vec3 fillColor = vec3(tex.x, tex.y, tex.z);


    st.x = mod(st.x, pct);

    st.x = step( fract(st.x * 1.0 / pct), 1.0 / pct) * fract(st.x);
    st.x *= texSmallPoints.r * 2.0; // subdivide for small circles
    st.x = fract(st.x);

    // Divide by 4
    st.y *= texSmallPoints.r * 2.0;
    st.y = fract(st.y);

    //float r = 0.425;
    float r = 0.4;
    float fillPct = circle(st, r, 1.0);

    vec2 center = vec2(0.5);
    float strokePct = stroke(st, center, r, 0.032 * texSmallPoints.r * 1.8);

    vec3 finalColor = vec3(1.0);
    vec3 strokeColor = fillColor;

    // todo -refactor if slow
    // todo - invert

    if (tex.a > 0.99) {
        strokeColor = black;
    }

    if (tex.a < 0.01) {
        strokeColor = white;
    }

    finalColor = mix(white, fillColor, fillPct);
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, strokeColor, 1. - strokePct);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor, 1.0);
}
```

And `GLKViewController`:

```
//
//  HomeOpenGLController.swift
//  Kobi
//
//  Created by Tibor Udvari on 14/06/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Tibor Udvari. All rights reserved.
//

import GLKit
import OpenGLES
import HEXColor

open class KobiOpenGLControllerBase: GLKViewController
{
    // --- Small points texture ---
    var gpuSmallColorsTexture = [GLubyte](repeating: 0, count: 0)

    var currentSmallPointTextureData: [GLubyte]? = nil

    // - allocated size
    let smallPointsTextureWidth = 128
    let smallPointsTextureHeight = 128

    // --- Color texture ---

    var gpuColorsTexture = [GLubyte](repeating: 0, count: 0)

    var currentColorsTextureData: [GLubyte]? = nil // size of grid

    // - allocated size
    let texWidth: Int = 256
    let texHeight: Int = 256

    // Grid - circles
    let cols = 31
    let rows = 22

    open let maxIdx: Int
    open let circleCount: Int

    // Grid - pixels
    var width: CGFloat  = 0.0
    var height: CGFloat = 0.0

    var circleWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    var circleHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    // OpenGL
    var program: GLuint = 0
    var circleProgram: GLuint = 0

    var context: EAGLContext? = nil

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        maxIdx = cols * rows
        circleCount = cols * rows
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // 0 is positive instead of 0
    func sign(_ x: Int) -> Int {
        let r = x < 0 ? -1 : 1
        return r
    }

    // MARK: - Setup

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        setupGridData()
    }

    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)  {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        setup() // because width and height is not initiated yet
    }

    func setupGridData(){

        //currentSmallPointTextureData = createCurrentSmallPointsTextureData()
    }


    func setup()
    {
        initTextures()

        self.context = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)

        if !(self.context != nil) {
            print("Failed to create ES context")
        }

        let view = self.view as! GLKView


        // Fix for "good" aspect ratio
        var frameSize = view.frame.size
        frameSize.height = frameSize.width / 1.43023255813953
        view.frame.size = frameSize

        // Should force the aspect ratio
        print("-------------")
        print("width \(view.frame.width) and height \(view.frame.height)")
        print("aspect ratio w/h \(view.frame.width / view.frame.height)")
        print("-------------")

        view.context = self.context!
        view.drawableColorFormat = .RGBA8888
        view.drawableMultisample = .multisample4X
        //view.drawableMultisample = .MultisampleNone
        //view.multipleTouchEnabled = true

        width = self.view.frame.size.width * self.view.contentScaleFactor
        height = self.view.frame.size.height * self.view.contentScaleFactor

        circleWidth = width / CGFloat(cols)
        circleHeight = height / CGFloat(rows)

        self.setupGL()

    }

    func initTextures()
    {
        gpuColorsTexture = [GLubyte](repeating: 0, count: Int(texWidth)*Int(texHeight)*4)
        gpuSmallColorsTexture = [GLubyte](repeating: 128, count: Int(smallPointsTextureWidth)*Int(smallPointsTextureHeight))
    }

    // MARK: - GLKView and GLKViewController delegate methods

    func sendTexturesToGPU() {
        for i in 0..<currentColorsTextureData!.count / 4 {
            let r = Int(i) / Int(cols)
            let c = Int(i) % cols

            let j = r * texWidth + c
            gpuColorsTexture[j*4]   = currentColorsTextureData![i * 4]; //= GLubyte(255);   // red
            gpuColorsTexture[j*4+1] = currentColorsTextureData![i * 4 + 1]; //GLubyte(random() % 255); // green
            gpuColorsTexture[j*4+2] = currentColorsTextureData![i * 4 + 2]; //GLubyte(0); // blue
            gpuColorsTexture[j*4+3] = currentColorsTextureData![i * 4 + 3]; // used for the stroke color
        }

        for i in 0..<currentSmallPointTextureData!.count{
            let r = Int(i) / Int(31 * 2)
            let c = Int(i) % (31 * 2)

            let j = r * 128 + c
            gpuSmallColorsTexture[j]   = currentSmallPointTextureData![i];
        }

        glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE1));
        glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLint(0), GL_LUMINANCE, GLsizei(smallPointsTextureWidth), GLsizei(smallPointsTextureHeight), GLint(0), GLenum(GL_LUMINANCE), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &gpuSmallColorsTexture)

        glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0));
        glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLint(0), GL_RGBA, GLsizei(texWidth), GLsizei(texHeight), GLint(0), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &gpuColorsTexture);
    }

    func update() {
        print("update")
        //todo

    }

    // todo  send a uniform array

    override open func glkView(_ view: GLKView, drawIn rect: CGRect) {
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))

        glEnable(GLenum(GL_DEPTH_TEST))
        glEnable(GLenum(GL_POINT_SIZE));
        glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
        glBlendFunc(GLenum(GL_SRC_ALPHA), GLenum(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA))
        glEnable(GLenum(GL_POINT_SMOOTH))

        // 22 x 15

        var baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        var modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, 1.5)
        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix)

        modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity
        glUseProgram(program)

        /*
        withUnsafePointer(to: &modelViewProjectionMatrix, {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Float.self, capacity: 16, {
                glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, $0)
            })
        })*/


        withUnsafePointer(to: &modelViewMatrix, {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: Float.self, capacity: 16, {
                glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix"), 1, 0, UnsafePointer($0))
            })
        })

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, squareVertices)
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "iResolution"), Float(width), Float(height), Float(texWidth), Float(texHeight))
        glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "gridSize"), Float(cols), Float(rows))

        glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP) , 0, 4)

        glUseProgram(circleProgram)
    }

    // MARK: - Texture

    func setupTextures()
    {
        let texInfo = try! GLKTextureLoader.texture(with: UIImage(named: "texture256")!.cgImage!, options: nil)

        glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0))
        glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0), (texInfo.name))
        //var dataTexture = (texInfo.name)
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "textureUnit"), 0)


        glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE1))
        let _ = createSmallPointsTexture()
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "smallPointsTextureUnit"), 1)
    }

    func createSmallPointsTexture() -> GLuint {
        var texture: GLuint = 1
        glGenTextures(GLsizei(1), &texture)

        glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture)

        glActiveTexture(texture)
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glGenerateMipmap(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D));

        return texture
    }

    // MARK: -  OpenGL ES 2 shader compilation

    func setupGL() {
        EAGLContext.setCurrent(self.context)

        let _ = self.loadShaders()

        glUseProgram(program)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

        self.setupTextures()
    }

    func tearDownGL() {
        EAGLContext.setCurrent(self.context)

        if program != 0 {
            glDeleteProgram(program)
            program = 0
        }
    }

    func loadShaders() -> Bool {
        var vertShader: GLuint = 0
        var fragShader: GLuint = 0
        var vertShaderPathname: String
        var fragShaderPathname: String

        // Create shader program.
        program = glCreateProgram()

        // Create and compile vertex shader.
        vertShaderPathname = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Shader", ofType: "vsh")!
        if self.compileShader(&vertShader, type: GLenum(GL_VERTEX_SHADER), file: vertShaderPathname) == false {
            print("Failed to compile vertex shader")
            return false
        }

        // Create and compile fragment shader.
        fragShaderPathname = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Shader", ofType: "fsh")!
        if !self.compileShader(&fragShader, type: GLenum(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER), file: fragShaderPathname) {
            print("Failed to compile fragment shader")
            /*
            var fragInfoLength: GLint = 0
            glGetShaderiv(fragShader, GLenum(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH), &fragInfoLength)

            //let cstring = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLchar>(allocatingCapacity: Int(fragInfoLength))
            var cstring = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLchar>(malloc(Int(fragInfoLength)))

            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragShader, fragInfoLength, nil, cstring)
            let shaderInfoLog = NSString(utf8String: cstring)
            print(shaderInfoLog)
            */
            return false
        }

        // Attach vertex shader to program.
        glAttachShader(program, vertShader)

        // Attach fragment shader to program.
        glAttachShader(program, fragShader)

        // Bind attribute locations.
        // This needs to be done prior to linking.
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position")

        // Link program.
        if !self.linkProgram(program) {
            print("Failed to link program: \(program)")

            if vertShader != 0 {
                glDeleteShader(vertShader)
                vertShader = 0
            }
            if fragShader != 0 {
                glDeleteShader(fragShader)
                fragShader = 0
            }
            if program != 0 {
                glDeleteProgram(program)
                program = 0
            }

            return false
        }

        // Release vertex and fragment shaders.
        if vertShader != 0 {
            glDetachShader(program, vertShader)
            glDeleteShader(vertShader)
        }
        if fragShader != 0 {
            glDetachShader(program, fragShader)
            glDeleteShader(fragShader)
        }

        return true
    }


    func compileShader(_ shader: inout GLuint, type: GLenum, file: String) -> Bool {
        var status: GLint = 0
        var source: UnsafePointer<Int8>
        do {
            source = try NSString(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue).utf8String!
        } catch {
            print("Failed to load vertex shader")
            return false
        }
        //var castSource = UnsafePointer<GLchar>(source)
        var castSource: UnsafePointer<GLchar>? = UnsafePointer<GLchar>(source)


        shader = glCreateShader(type)
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &castSource, nil)
        glCompileShader(shader)

        var logLength: GLint = 0
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GLenum(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH), &logLength)

        if logLength > 0 {
            //var log = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLchar>(malloc(Int(logLength)))
            print("Log length gt 0")
            /*
            var log = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLchar>(malloc(Int(logLength)))

            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength, &logLength, log)
            NSLog("Shader compile log: \n%s", log)
            free(log)
            */
        }

        glGetShaderiv(shader, GLenum(GL_COMPILE_STATUS), &status)
        if status == 0 {
            glDeleteShader(shader)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func linkProgram(_ prog: GLuint) -> Bool {
        var status: GLint = 0
        glLinkProgram(prog)

        //#if defined(DEBUG)
        //        var logLength: GLint = 0
        //        glGetShaderiv(shader, GLenum(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH), &logLength)
        //        if logLength > 0 {
        //            var log = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLchar>(malloc(Int(logLength)))
        //            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, logLength, &logLength, log)
        //            NSLog("Shader compile log: \n%s", log)
        //            free(log)
        //        }
        //#endif

        glGetProgramiv(prog, GLenum(GL_LINK_STATUS), &status)
        if status == 0 {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    func validateProgram(_ prog: GLuint) -> Bool {
        var logLength: GLsizei = 0
        var status: GLint = 0

        glValidateProgram(prog)
        glGetProgramiv(prog, GLenum(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH), &logLength)
        if logLength > 0 {
            var log: [GLchar] = [GLchar](repeating: 0, count: Int(logLength))
            glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, &log)
            print("Program validate log: \n\(log)")
        }

        glGetProgramiv(prog, GLenum(GL_VALIDATE_STATUS), &status)
        var returnVal = true
        if status == 0 {
            returnVal = false
        }
        return returnVal
    }

    // MARK : Cleanup

    override open func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        if self.isViewLoaded && (self.view.window != nil) {
            self.view = nil

            self.tearDownGL()

            if EAGLContext.current() === self.context {
                EAGLContext.setCurrent(nil)
            }
            self.context = nil
        }
    }

    deinit {
        self.tearDownGL()

        if EAGLContext.current() === self.context {
            EAGLContext.setCurrent(nil)
        }
    }

}

var squareVertices: [GLfloat] = [
    -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,
];
```

Comment: Who can answer your question if you don't show code drawing the circle ? Did you draw a circle in your fragment shader code or vertex shader? It doesn't really matter Retina or not to draw objects in the framebuffer because view frame size is not always equal to FBO size.

Comment: I made an update with all the code pertaining to this. I feel it must be some sort of setup issue because the cut-off is very steep, and only present on one device, while working perfectly fine on others.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for updating. I am not sure exactly which part caused it but I am sure it must happen in your fragment shader code.

I guess vec2 **st**'s value changing is not steady there while it is being calculated.

I want you to test this to see if it is your fragment shader.

just draw only 1 circle without uniform values except iResolution.
only using iResolution and gl_FragCoord, draw a circle.

I think it's going to properly show up. Then go over your FS.

Comment: Hello. It still seems to be working fine. I have further updated the question with screenshots for clarity.

Comment: @TiborUdvari when you draw a circle in FS, it was fine to show up on every devices, right?  I think it is not a problem about Retina or not. You don't make smooth curves there (red area you updated) so please go over your Fragment Shader with uniform variables